# Django admin download reportlab PDF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, pdf-generation, reportlab

I use this guide(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/outputting-pdf/) to download PDF. It works on regular public page. But I am trying to get it working in the admin for a specific model and have model data on the PDF.

In my admin I have:

`cakes/models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Cake(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField("Date ordered")
    name = models.CharField()

    def pdf_link(self):
        from django.utils.html import format_html
        return format_html("<a href='pdf/%s/'>Download PDF</a>" % self.pk)
```

Dislay the PDF link in the django admin. The link is showing up in admin, it just doesn't link to the PDF yet(pass `pdf_link`)...

`cakes/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Cake


@admin.register(Cake)
class CakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'customer',
        'date',
        'pdf_link',
    )
```

On my `cakes.views.py` I have the `generate_pdf` function from the django docs.

How do I connect/link my view function(`generate_pdf`) with the `pdf_link` function in my model?

I can download the PDF outside the admin. I'm just not sure how to tie it all together in the admin.